# For more details see: ’go help gopath’

Tags: macos, go

I'm learning Go and I have some problem.

I following

```
go install
```

But an error:

```
no install location for directory /Users/skan/documents/study/golang/src/section1 outside GOPATH

For more details see: ’go help gopath’
```

so I return to my .bash/profile

this is my .bash/profile

```
# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by ’conda init’ !!
__conda_setup=”$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false ’/anaconda3/bin/conda’ shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)”
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
\eval ”$__conda_setup”
else
if [ -f ”/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh” ]; then
. ”/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh”
CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
else
\export PATH=”/anaconda3/bin:$PATH:$GOPATH:$GOBIN”
fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
export GOPATH="/Users/skan/Documetns/study/golang"
export GOBIN=$GOPATH/bin
```

Comment: So what did you learn when you ran `go help gopath` as instructed?

Comment: Typo only. Rule of thumb: If something does not work out: Check for typos at least 3 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
mkdir -p $GOPATH/bin
```

The error you're seeing is the *installation* directory doesn't exist, so install can't do anything.

---

Also, there's a typo here:

```
export GOPATH="/Users/skan/Documetns/study/golang"
```

So, same reasoning, but, try `Documents`